# Why is the first lightsaber form also called The Way of the Sarlacc?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

The first lightsaber form (Form I) is also known as Shii-Cho, the determination form or The Way of the Sarlacc. As asked above, why The Way of the Sarlacc?
If I remember right, in Episode VI, Luke and Han are sentenced by Jabba to be thrown into this Sarlacc pit, where the Sarlacc monster lives. Probably not, but does this Sarlacc have anything in common with Shii-Cho Sarlacc? I am convinced that this is just a name coincidence. But I would still like to know, **who or what was this Sarlacc?** (the Shii-Cho one)

Comment: Well, it is also called the Determination Form, is it not? This implies something that takes time and effort - like being digested in the stomach of a Sarlacc for 1000 years.

Comment: Probably because you just flail your arms about like tentacles.

Comment: @Mystagogue - Like [this](http://i.imgur.com/9885O.gif)?

Comment: They both had a bunch of CGI added later on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shii-Cho appears to be named after the Sarlacc because of [the action of its tentacles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r4Co.gif), persistently waving around in the hopes of getting past a prey's defences.

> Also known as the Determination Form or the Way of the Sarlacc, **Form I
> teaches the basic moves of attack and parry,** focusing on the humanoid
> body's target zones: left side, right side, head, and legs.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Jedi Path: A Manual for Students of the Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_(real-life_book))</sup></sub>

Note the driving action, persistently pushing the blade forward at the enemy.

[image]

[image]

You may also want to note that one of the (Form I) special moves described in the [Saga Edition Jedi Academy Training Manual](http://www.theberserker.net/berserker/sw/rule_books/SW_Saga_Jedi_Academy_Training_Manual.pdf) is called the **Sarlacc Sweep**, a move which evidently involves waving your blade in a wide sweeping motion.

[image]

---

For the record, Form II is nicknamed "***the Way of the Ysalamiri***" because of the creature's tenacity and refusal to be budged from its standpoint, Form III is "***the Way of the Mynock***" because of that creature's tendency to wrap itself in its leathery wings to protect itself from predators, Form IV is "***the Way of the Hawk-Bat***" because of the practitioner's tendency to jump around like a hyper-kinetic imbecile, Form V is "***the Way of the Krayt Dragon***" because of the user's tendency to dominate their opponents with their stature and size, Form VI is "***the Way of the Rancor***" because of its intense aggression and Form VII is "***the Way of the Vornskr***" due to its viciousness and unpredictability.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Form_I/Legends), which is the closest thing you're likely to get to a canon answer on this:

> The simplicity and persistent methods of the form led it to being dubbed the "Way of the Sarlacc" and the "Determination Form".

The [Sarlacc](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sarlacc/Legends) from Return of the Jedi is the same creature as the one referenced by Form I.

As for why a Sarlacc should be the creature emblematic of the Determination Form, I think Adamant's comment was spot on. The Sarlacc digests its prey for over 1000 years, which can suggest Determination to someone naming a lightsaber style.

Comment: It's not called the determination form because it requines determination  (patience), it's called the determination form because your future fighting style is determined (chosen) as a result of your mastery of Form 1